# Label Text Stack after setFontScale Libgdx

Tags: libgdx

After scaling my label to fit into box2d environment, my label text will stack together looks like this:

[image: Stacked text]

It suppose to be abc123.

My codes are as below:

```
    Label label = new Label("abc123",game.getUiSkin());
    Container container = new Container<Label>(label);
    container.setTransform(true);
    label.setFontScale(1/GC.UNITS_PER_METER);
    container.pack();
    box2dStage.addActor(container);
```

I'm using container for label because want to apply scaling action on it. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove container.pack();  method.

Comment: Without container.pack, my label isn't appealing at all :(